# KineticJS: How to allow only one Shape be draggable at the time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have two shapes (images) on a KineticJS layer.

See the following image:

[image]

The blue shape is the background which is set

```
 backgroundShape.draggable(true);
```

The green shape is set

```
somedShape.draggable(true);
```

Both shapes are on the same layer. I use this stage on a mobile multi touch device. When I use two fingers as marked with the red points in the following image and move the two fingers on the device both shapes are moving.

[image]

**Is there a way to restrict that the second shap is moving while the first shape is moving?**

Comment: Can you provide any demo?